# How do Games (e.g. Counter Strike) find local network servers

Tags: javascript, networking, webserver, webrtc, p2p

I'm researching about servers and P2P and I remember that while playing CS on a local network, without an internet connection the client was able to fetch the servers on the local network. How is that possible? I really would like to implement something similar to that in WebRTC, although I believe it's not possible with WebRTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peer discovery on a LAN is commonly done via UDP multicast which indeed is not available via browser APIs.